# Change event not firing for programmatic changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML select dropdown whose value may be edited programmatically. My change event fires when the user edits the value from the page, but not when the value is changed in the code. I need the event to fire in both cases. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

```
$("#dropdownId").on('change', function () {
    //do stuff
});
...
var df = document.frmMain;
df.dropdownId.value = someValue; //change event does not fire
```

Comment: Have you tried encapsulating the change function into an actual function? That way you can call it manually when you modify the dropdown list.

Comment: It is 'by design'. Change event getting triggerred when the value is changed programmatically is bad.

Answer (score 13):

You can use  jQuery's `.trigger` to fire an event. In your case:

```
$("#dropdownId").trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to manually fire the event using jquery trigger function after settig the value :

```
 $("#dropdownId").trigger('change');
```

Comment: Just watch out for the risk of your code accidentally doing a listener/trigger recursive cycle. (That's actually why by default it doesn't fire that)

Comment: Should this really happen when firing a single trigger @Katana314?

Answer (score 1):

use jquery to set selection and for fire change event.

```
$('#'+df.dropdownId).val(someValue).change();
```